# Correct position of adverb "persistently" in verb phrase "act on it"?

Tags: adverb-position

What's the correct position of the adverb "persistently" in the verb phrase "act on it"?

Should it be `persistently act on it` or `act on it persistently`?

Thanks

Comment: Both sound OK to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what emphasis you want. As "persistently" modifies the verb "act", my recommendation for the choices given is "persistently act on it". Another variation "act persistently on it" would also work.